# How to submit an input field with enter in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I've made an input field in react that takes in a value and is supposed to be submitted using the enter key but I haven't been able to get it to work.

```
<input
  key = "searchBox"
  type = "text"
  value = {this.state.currentValue}
  placeholder = "Search"
  onChange = {this.handleChange}
  onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}
/>
```

At the moment, enter does nothing. I've tried wrapping this in a form element where `onSubmit` is now part of that form element but when I do that, the entire input field disappears. So, how can I submit this by using enter? Here's the rest of the code.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class searchClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit = {() => alert("yes")}>  
        <input
          key = "searchBox"
          type = "text"
          value = {this.state.currentValue}
          placeholder = "Search"
          onChange = {this.handleChange}
        />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Here's part of my render function in App.js.

```
    return (
      <div className = "tableWrapper">
        <div id = "tableScroll">
            <table>
              <SearchClass />
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
```

Comment: wrap it in a `<form></form>`

Comment: I did that and the entire input disappears.

Comment: can you include more code plz

Comment: also you should remove the `onSubmit` from the input and add it to the form.

Comment: Alright, I added the rest of the code, and I wrapped it in the <form> tags and added onSubmit to the form but the input field is still missing. If I remove the <form> tags then the input field shows up again.

Comment: it should be `<input` not `<input>`

Comment: and if thats a typo add another input for submit. `<input type="submit"/>`

Comment: I tried that and the input field no longer accepts text. It appears to just be a submit button now.

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

`input` elements don't really do anything with an `onSubmit` prop/attribute.

```
<input
  key = "searchBox"
  type = "text"
  value = {this.state.currentValue}
  placeholder = "Search"
  onChange = {this.handleChange}
  onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit} // useless
/>
```

## Solution

Wrap your input in a form and prevent the default form action from occurring, this is reloading the page, and your app.

```
class SearchClass extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentValue: ""
  };

  handleChange = (e) => this.setState({ currentValue: e.target.value });
  render() {
    return (
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent the default form action
          alert("yes");
        }}
      >
        <input
          key="searchBox"
          type="text"
          value={this.state.currentValue}
          placeholder="Search"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit focused-pare-dnic7]

Comment: The problem is that nothing shows up if I wrap this in <form> tags. If I remove the <form> tags and add onSubmit to the input field then pressing enter still does nothing.

Comment: @JoshSusa What do you mean nothing shows up? Did you even open the sandbox and see it running? I see it working as you wanted in the sandbox. Is there more to your code/issue then?

Comment: I mean nothing is showing up. This code is currently part of a component class in React. It seems like nothing shows up only in this component because if I do the same thing in App.js, it then shows up. Is there something about React component classes that causes anything wrapped in the form tags to not show up?

Comment: @JoshSusa Nope. Only whatever else you may be doing in the class component. Can you share a complete code example that reproduces your issue? I copy/pasted ***your*** class-component code into a sandbox and applied fix and it's working there. Clearly you've something else going on in your code, like maybe an early return or something, but we won't know until we can get eyes on it.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is but I don't know how to fix it. The problem is that the element is inside of a table. The problem is that based on what I'm trying to do, I need each instance of the component to be inside the table.

Comment: @JoshSusa That is a completely separate and different issue. Please post a new question regarding this other issue if you like. That being said, I don't see any reason why multiples of `SearchClass` can't be rendered at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class searchClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={() => alert("yes")}>  
        <input
          key="searchBox"
          type="text"
          value={this.state.currentValue}
          placeholder="Search"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make a search box/input? You can use `<input type="search"/>`. Wrap it with form tag.